# What does it mean by "put to sea upon a sieve for money"?

Tags: meaning

I was reading an article which I found here https://newrepublic.com/article/139769/cash-words-brief-history-writing-money

Would anybody please explain?

For clarity, I am copying the whole paragraph in below.

> Simonides changed this. He wrote for money, and he kept precise books. Despite his undisputed literary excellence, this quality came to define him above all else: Simonides was thought to be parsimonious, a miser, putting money above all else. Ailian, his biographer, commented simply that “No one would deny that Simonides loved money.” In Aristophanes’s Peace, Simonides is described as one who would **“put to sea upon a sieve for money.”** It is to Simonides, agree most classical commentators, that we owe our current estrangement from our words. As Anne Carson puts it in the Economy of the Unlost, her study of Simonides and Paul Celan: “I like to think Simonides represents an early, severe form of economic alienation and the ‘doubleness’ that attends it.”

Comment: He would take unbelievably stupid risks for money. Sailing in a sieve will get you about 0 meters away from the shore.

Answer (score 5):

In [*A New Variorum Edition of Shakespeare: Macbeth*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tvg7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22to+sea+in+a+sieve%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg44mvxMjRAhVX22MKHZatDJQQ6AEITzAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20sea%20in%20a%20sieve%22&f=false) (1873), the First Witch speaks as follows:

> A sailor's wife had chestnuts in her lap,/ And mounch'd, and mounch'd, and mounch'd. 'Give me,' quoth I:/ 'Aroint thee, witch!' the rump-fed ronyon cries./ Her husband's to Aleppo gone, master o' the Tiger:/ But **in a sieve I'll thither sail**,/ And, like a rat without a tail,/ I'll do, I'll do, and I'll do.

The notes to this speech then quote Steevens (an earlier annotator of Shakespeare) to this effect:

> Scott, in his *Discovery of Witchcraft*, 1584, says it was believed that witches 'could sail in an egg shell, a cockle or muscle shell, through and under the tempestuous seas.' Again, Sir W. Davenant says, in his Albovine, 1629: 'He sits like a witch **sailing in a sieve**.' Again, in 'Newes from Scotland: Declaring the damnable Life of Doctor Fian, a notable Sorcerer, who was burned at Edinbrough in Januarie lat, 1591 ; which Doctor was Register to the Devill, that sundrie Times,' &c..... 'Discovering ho they pretended to bewitch and drowne his Majestie in the Sea, comming from Denmarke,' &c. we read: 'Item—Agnis Tompson was brought again before the kings majesty and his council, and being examined of the meetings and detestable dealings of those witches, she confessed upon the night of All-hallawn-even last she was accompanied as well with the persons aforesaid, as also with a great many other witches, to the number of two hundred, and that they altogether **went by sea, each one in a riddle or sieve**, and went in the same very substantially with flaggons of wine, making merry and drinking by the way in the same riddles or sieves to the kirk of North Berwick in Lothian, and that after they had landed they took hands on the land and danced this reel or short dance, singing all with one voice,— Commer goe ye before, commer goe ye,/ Gif you will not goe before, commer let me!'
>
> CLARENDON. In Greek επι ριπους πλειν, ' to **go to sea in a sieve**,' was a proverbial expression for an enterprise of extreme hazard or impossible of achievement.

So in English tradition, the sailing sieve is rather closely connected to black magic. But since Aristophanes was Greek and antedates Shakespeare by almost 2000 years, his description of Simonides is likely untainted by the dark wing of witchcraft. Certainly the Greek sense of the hazards and futility of going to sea in a sieve (rather than any occult skills that might make such an endeavor successful) seems to be central to the Simonides episode—the sense there being that money was so attractive to Simonides that he would dare to do anything (however foolish) to get it.

But in later years, lighter-hearted accounts of sieve-seafaring are extant in English texts as well. One popular instance is Edward Lear's poem, "[The Jumblies](https://books.google.com/books?id=-8A7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA445&dq=%22to+sea+in+a+sieve%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg44mvxMjRAhVX22MKHZatDJQQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22to%20sea%20in%20a%20sieve%22&f=false)," reprinted (rather incongruously) in *The Church Eclectic: A Monthly Magazine of Church Opinion, Religious Literature, and Ecclesiastical Miscellany*" (December 1875):

> They went to sea in a sieve, they did,/ In a sieve they went to sea; In spite of all their friends could say,/ On a winter's morn, on a stormy day,/ In a sieve they went to sea!/ And when the sieve turned round and round,/ And every one cried, " You'll all be drowned!"/ They called aloud, "Our sieve ain't big,/ But we don't care a button! we don't care a fig!"/In a sieve we'll go to sea!"

To the astonishment of all, everything turns out well for the Jumblies, so perhaps the poem offers a message at some level about the shielding power of faith. Or maybe the Jumblies used sorcery, along with their "pinky papers," to stay dry.

Comment: Given that the Simonedes quote is about money, would the 'pinky paper' be the Financial Times? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=financial+times&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFqrGJ98jRAhUrBMAKHbSCAMAQ_AUICSgC&biw=808&bih=601&dpr=1

Answer (score 2):

This is an accusation that the poet Simonides loved money more than anything else; that he could easily be bought, even if the requirement were something very dangerous or ludicrous.

> Simonides: A highly respected poet, he was however notorious for demanding high fees - he'd even go to sea in a sieve if the commission was right (line 697-8). [[Wikipedia]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_(play))